# Close alertify.js log from code

Tags: javascript, alertifyjs

I'm using the [alertify.js](https://alertifyjs.org/) library to create a persistent log that cannot be clicked on to hide.

```
var log = alertify.closeLogOnClick(false).delay(0).log("Hello world!");
```

How can I close this `log` I've just created from within my JavaScript code?

Comment: Try this `alertify.delay(0).log("Hello world!");` so this will show up continuously. and only on the click it will get closed.

Comment: I obviously set `closeLogOnClick(false)` as you can see in my code. That's not really a solution.

Comment: Variable `log` has a method `clearLogs()`

Comment: `alertify.clearLogs()`

Comment: @Mark Nijboer Yeah I saw that, but I wanted to avoid it in case there are other logs visible that i don't want to be closed.

Comment: I ended up adding my own `close()` method to the actual library itself. This is until someone can provide me with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have created 4 persistent logs,

```
var log = alertify.closeLogOnClick(false).delay(0).log("Hello world!");
var log1 = alertify.closeLogOnClick(false).delay(0).log("Hello world1!");
var log2 = alertify.closeLogOnClick(false).delay(0).log("Hello world2!");
var log3 = alertify.closeLogOnClick(false).delay(0).log("Hello world3!");
```

This will create 4 log,

To clear a specific log, some kind of if condition if you want to.

First to list out all the logs, 
`$(".alertify-logs")`

running this you will all the items,
`$(".alertify-logs").children` and check with the log text to remove it.

For eg: `$(".alertify-logs").children[0].innerText == "Hello world!"` then `$(".alertify-logs").children[0].remove();`